# Spring AOP aspects ruined the context

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I'm facing a pretty weird trouble. I use annotation-driven AspectJ in my App. When I try to proceed my method, I receive null pointers on my autowired fields. (In the service class, which methods I'm invoking in the interceptor). Before the usage of AspectJ the spring context was working just fine. I'm providing my code, maybe I just don't see that small mistake :( Spent TOO MUCH time finding it. :(

Here goes the Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeInterceptor{

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeInterceptor.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("webServiceResponseFactory")
protected WebServiceResponseFactory responseFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("configBean")
protected ConfigBean configBean;

public SomeServiceInterceptor () {
    LOGGER.info("Some service interceptor was created");
}

@Around("execution(public * pathToMyClassIsCorrect.*(..))")
public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    String securityTokenForMethod = pjp.getArgs()[0].toString();
    if (securityTokenForMethod != null) {
        LOGGER.info("Proceeding the securityTokenCheck before calling method "
                + pjp.getSignature().getName());
        if (validateAccessToken(securityTokenForMethod)) {
            return responseFactory
                    .buildFailedResponse("securityAccessToken is invalid for this request");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Throwable("There was an exception before calling method "
                + pjp.getSignature().getName());
    }

    try {
        LOGGER.info("Calling method " + pjp.getSignature().getName());
        Object methodToInvoke = pjp.proceed();
        LOGGER.info("Method " + pjp.getSignature().getName()
                + " was called successfully");
        return methodToInvoke;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        LOGGER.info("Method " + pjp.getSignature().getName() + "threw an exception. ");
        boolean verboseError = Boolean.parseBoolean(pjp.getArgs()[1].toString());

        return responseFactory.buildErrorResponse(e, verboseError);
    }
}

}
```

My app-context.xml has all of the compontent-scan packages included and the  enabled.

Any help is very appreciated.

EDIT

Also, right after the invocation I receive such error:

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
```

EDIT 2.0:

Just tried to launch the service without the aspect, works fine. So the trouble is really caused by the aspect that intercepts the method of service. :\

EDIT 3.0:

I have added a logger to the constructor. So, as I see, the object is not even created. No idea what could be the reason.

EDIT 4.0: 
AspectJ configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
    "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug">
    <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
    <include within="com.store.*"/>
    <include within="com.store.services.*"/>
</weaver>
<aspects>
    <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
    <aspect name="com.store.services.StoreServiceAspect"/>
</aspects>
</aspectj>

<weaver options="-verbose">
<include within="javax.*" />
<include within="org.aspectj.*" />
<include
    within="(!@NoWeave com.store.services.*) AND com.bsro.storewebsrv.services.*" />

<dump within="com.store.services.*" />
</weaver>
```

Comment: Do you use AspectJ or AspectJ-style Spring AOP? There's a big difference!

Comment: See [Spring AOP or AspectJ?](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-spring-or-aspectj)

Comment: I've rolled all over that documentation :(

Comment: Still, your question title and the second sentence contradict each other. Which is it: Spring AOP or AspectJ?

Comment: It is AspectJ, yeah. My bad. Just too tired :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was that the ltw was not working, because of lack of "Loader" in the app context in Tomcat. So following the 8.8.3 reference guide in Spring, pretty much fixed it. The "aspectOf" was not found because of the reason told above. This error is thrown any times the weaving is failing. Also, the autowired fields became null because of the weaving errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your error-handling code is dangerously vulnerable:

```
LOGGER.info("Method " + pjp.getSignature().getName() + "threw an exception. ");
boolean verboseError = Boolean.parseBoolean(pjp.getArgs()[1].toString());
```

There is a number of opportunities for a new exception that masks the one you just caught. Make the exception handler bulletproof: don't parse anything and don't expose yourself to an NPE by calling methods on possibly-null values.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, just fixed that. But no changes.

Answer (score 1):

I am basing this on your last comment, that this is AspectJ aspect.

`@Autowired` will not work with AspectJ aspects. The fix is to use a factory method `aspectOf` to inject in what you require in your aspect this way:

```
<bean class="SomeInterceptor" factory-method="aspectOf">
  <property name="webServiceResponseFactory" ref="..."/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Just got "no matching factory method found: factory method 'aspectOf' error."

Comment: Okay, then something is off in your set-up of AspectJ because `aspectOf` and `hasAspect` methods are injected by the AspectJ compiler into the aspects. Can you please share a little bit more of your aspects related configuration

Comment: Thanks, so you are essentially using load time weaving right - if so can you please show configuration of how you have set up ltw - the instrumentation jar etc, just to make sure that it is set up correctly

Comment: aop.xml updated. Also, my context contains the <context:load-time-weaver />

Comment: The weaver options that you have "-verbose -showWeaveInfo -debug" should have shown which classes are being woven right - can you confirm that you are seeing the relevant classes being woven. Also the @Component annotation should be removed from the aspect(should not have any side effects,but in case). I am assuming you are also starting your jvm with `-javaagent:`?